# set name attribute with increasing number in jquery

Tags: jquery, input, attributes

I have the following code in Jquery:

```
.find("input").attr('name', + cloneCount++)
```

What I would like is that the value of the name attribute has it's current value + with the increasing value of the cloneCount var.

Any ideas how I can do this?

=================
UPDATE

Thank you all for your quick replies, but i've realised that I didnt give enough code:

```
    var cloneCount = 1;
   $(".button").click(function(){

      $('#id')
          .clone()
          .attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount++)
          .insertAfter($('[id^=id]:last'))
         .find("input").attr('name', parseInt(attr('name')) + cloneCount++)
   }); 
});
```

What i would like is that when a div is cloned all input fields get a different value for the name attribute. The number of inputs is variable. So let's say we have an input with name="example", The cloned version should get name="example2" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myInput = ....find("input");
myInput.attr('name', parseInt(myInput.attr('name')) + cloneCount++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `.attr()` can take in a function that can return the value you need applied to the attribute.

```
.find('input').attr('name', function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr('name'), 10) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i check the value of the name attribute it returns an error (NaN)

Answer (score 0):

for (i=0;i<10000000;i++)
{

cloneCount++;

.find("input").attr('name',cloneCount)

}

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
var cloneCount = 1;
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('name', cloneCount)
  cloneCount ++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the value of the name attribute gets 1,2,3, etc... What i would like is that the value gets its orignal value + the value of the cloneCount var. So name, name1, name2 etc. (See update in my question)